# Alterar src de imagem

Tags: jquery, asp

Tenho um campo que chama img, nele eu gravo o nome da imagem, por exemplo: 001.jpg, onde "1" corresponde ao ID do registro.

Tenho uma rotina que altera a imagem e está funcionando, a alteração é feita por jQuery e ASP.

Mas quando altero a imagem, a rotina salva com o mesmo nome, ou seja, apaga a imagem anterior e salva a nova com o mesmo nome: 001.jpg

É onde esta o problema: Altero o atributo `src` via jQuery, está funcionando porque coloquei um teste e alterou o nome, porém o nome não é alterado e somente a imagem na pasta.

Ou seja, como o `src` não é alterado a imagem também não muda.

E se eu alterar o nome da imagem no banco de dados dá na mesma, porque imagine a situação:

```
figura atual: 001.jpg
figura nova : 001-x.jpg
```

Lá no banco ficou a última e quando eu for fazer a alteração, novamente será alterada para 001-x.jpg ou seja nunca vai mudar o atributo `src`.

Estou na lógica certa ou falta algo?

O que eu ja fiz:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "usuarios-acoes.asp?IdReg=" + IdReg + "&Acao=" + Acao + "&nomeUsu=" + nomeUsu,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(result) {
    if (result == "N") {} else {
      $('#IdUsuarioImg').val('');
      $('#titNomeModalImg').html('');
      $('#img-peq-usu-' + IdReg).attr('src', result);
      $('#img-gde-usu-' + IdReg).attr('src', result);
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    $('#IdUsuarioImg').val('');
    $('#titNomeModalImg').html('');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Se alterar o src e o que você precisa você pode usar o exemplo 1, se for alterar o seletor o exemplo 2 e se for criar dinamicamente exemplo 3.

```js
// 1 Para mudar o caminho da imagem
var id = 3;
var test = $("#imagem").attr('src', '00' + id + '.jpg');
console.log(test);

// 2 Para mudar o Seletor da imagem
var test2 = $('#imagem' + id).attr("src", "001.jpg");
console.log(test2);

// 3 Para criar o seletor e a url Dinamicamente
var test3 = "<img id='imagem" + id + "' src='00" + id + ".jpg' alt='imagem" + id + "'><br>";
$("#imagemDinamica").append(test3);
console.log(test3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='imagem' src='001.jpg' alt='imagem1'>
<br>
<img id='imagem2' src='001.jpg' alt='imagem2'>
<br>
<div id="imagemDinamica">
</div>
```

Comment: Meu objetivo é mostrar a nova imagem que acabou de ser salva.

Quando eu salvo a imagem eu retorno para o ajax apenas o nome e com isso altero o attr src. ou seja o sistema troca 001.jpg para 001.jpg, mas a imagem é outra.

eu não entendi isso que postou, poderia me dar uma luz ?

Comment: Você precisa salvar a imagem colocando  um id nela e depois mostrar? Pode colocar o código que você já fez para entender a sua lógica ?

Comment: Apaga o coment e edita o seu post colocando o seu código você pode usar <pre> código </pre> pra destacar e identar

Comment: O código de salvar é somente o Upload e depois eu dou um response que é pego por ajax

<pre>
   $.ajax({
    url: "usuarios-acoes.asp?IdReg="+IdReg+"&Acao="+Acao+"&nomeUsu="+nomeUsu,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(result){
     if(result == "N"){
     }
     else{
       
      $('#IdUsuarioImg').val('');
      $('#titNomeModalImg').html('');
      $('#img-peq-usu-'+IdReg).attr('src', result); 
      $('#img-gde-usu-'+IdReg).attr('src', result); 
  
     }
    },
    error: function(){
     $('#IdUsuarioImg').val('');
     $('#titNomeModalImg').html('');
    }   
   });

</pre>

Comment: Não posso usar seu exemplo 1 porque os "00" não são fixos, vai aumentando.

no meu código tem a variavel result, nela eu retorno o nome da imagem, sendo assim, já estou fazendo o seu exemplo 2, concorda ?

e em ambos os casos não resolveu, o script chega a trocar o nome da imagem, mas o meu problema é que antes tinha uma imagem e agora é outra figura mas com o mesmo nome.

Comment: Em vez de pegar o Id Pegue o nome da imagem toda

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26229/discussion-between-gabriel-rodrigues-and-ronaldo-bueno).

Comment: mas eu não estou pegando o ID, só foi um exemplo, estou pegando o nome da imagem para mostrar no result